# window.resizeTo works differently in IE alone

Tags: javascript

window.resizeTo will work fine until the present window (yet to be resized) is far away from task bar.If it is near to task bar it compresses the size.I hope im clear.It is observed in IE.
To explain it clearly
go to :http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_window_resizeto
give size as some 400,550
and minimize the window and move it below task bar .
Now click Resize window
It will be resized to a lower size.
I observed in IE only

Comment: I see that resizing makes it not appear lower than the taskbar itself - it tries to float on the task bar so to say. I.e. the window gets a smaller height than it otherwise would. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes its not allowing to appear lower than task bar

Comment: You could try to move it up enough so that IE allows you to resize fully, then move it down again.

Comment: by doing so it is again resizing

Answer (score 2):

It's a security feature so that web developers don't do bad things, like moving windows off screen.

Due to this and the fact that it can be deactivated in the user configuration of most browsers, you should not rely on `resizeTo` in the first place, and make your web site/web app work without using it.